# JLabel from one panel link to another JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

I'm suppose to create a game using java app. I have a few JLabel with images in a JPanel and I would like to link these JLabels from a JPanel to different JPanel. Is it possible to do so? As in when the Jlabel is being clicked, another page will appear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "link"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Set the cursor for the label to [`Cursor.HAND_CURSOR`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Cursor.html#HAND_CURSOR).
- Add a [`MouseListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) to each label.

  - On [`mouseEntered()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html#mouseEntered%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29), set the color of the link text to a different color to high-light it (like a browser would).
  - On [`mouseClicked()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html#mouseClicked%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29), change cards in a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) to show the  other components, or otherwise reveal the other components.

Answer (score 2):

Swing components can't be shared as they can only have a single parent.

However you can share the Icon of the label with another Swing component. So in your MouseListener you can use  the `getIcon()` method of the label you clicked on. Then you can add the icon to another component is the second panel using the `setIcon(...)` method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be more specific. You need to include things like what technologies you're using. Is this a web based project? Is it a stand alone application? And what specifically you're trying to do. And "link" has too broad of a meaning. That could mean a lot of different things. You have to be more specific in order to get the proper help.

Comment: Your answer isn't an answer; it's a comment.

Comment: @Paul users with reputations less 50 can't post comments anywhere

Comment: Erm, I'm suppose to create a game using java app. As in, when the Jlabel is being clicked, another page will appear.

Comment: Ah. Ic. If you mean another appletviewer window than I don't know how to do that. If you mean another web page than that's pretty easy. Create a mouselistener for your JLabel and when you override the mouseclicked method insert getAppletContext().showDocument(url);

Answer (score 0):

You can share the JLabel by making it a singleton like class.

```
public class SharedJLabel {
    private static JLabel imageLabel;
    static {
        //init the imageLabel here
    }

    public static JLabel getImageLabel() {
        return imageLabel;
    }
}
```

In your different JPanel classes, you can just use this class to use the shared JLabel:

```
SharedJLabel.getSharedImageLabel();
```